# How to fix "declared ‘static’ but never defined" on member function?

Tags: c++

I'm working on implementing an IRC client (a bit anachronistic, I know), and have hit a wall due to this perplexing compilation warning (g++ 7.4.0). This does not occur at all under clang, but I prefer g++ and would like to appease it if at all possible.

```
In file included from src/client/server_context.cpp:3:0:
src/protocol/numeric.h:52:15: error: ‘silica::protocol::prototype
    silica::protocol::numeric_impl<NumericCode, SymbolicName, NumArgs>::
    getPrototype() const [with const char* NumericCode =
    (& silica::protocol::NUM_RPL_ENDOFMOTD);
    const char* SymbolicName = (& silica::protocol::SYM_RPL_ENDOFMOTD);
    int NumArgs = 0]’ declared ‘static’ but never defined [-Werror=unused-function]
    prototype getPrototype() const override { return s_prototype; }
```

There are duplicates for other instantiations of the template.

However, I am completely lost as to how the function is either static (I suppose it is talking about visibility exclusive to the translation unit, rather than 'static' in the object-oriented sense) or undefined (the definition is right there!).

The template containing this method has been instantiated successfully in other places throughout my code, and the above vomit only occurs if I call `getPrototype()` in this particular context.

Now, some context:

- `numeric_impl` is a template class for defining an RFC 1459 numeric code
- Each instantiation of `numeric_impl` is derived from `numeric_base`
- `numeric_base` is derived from `protobase` (representing a base class for protocol messages)
- For each unique type of message, there exists a `prototype` for that message (basically just a struct containing its name and other properties of the message type)
- `protobase` defines `virtual prototype getPrototype()` so I can determine the type of a particular message at runtime
- Each specific message type also has a `static prototype Prototype()` which useful for stuff like checking `someMessage.getPrototype() == some_message_type::Prototype()`

The code triggering the error is essentially as follows:

```cpp
void server_context::connect(/* omitted irrelevant args */) {

    // Omitted irrelevant code that attempts to connect to the server

    // This call waits for a reply to the command that was sent above
    std::shared_ptr<protobase> res = client->wait_for(
        {err_nonicknamegiven::Prototype(), err_erroneusnickname::Prototype(), err_nicknameinuse::Prototype(),
         err_nickcollision::Prototype(), err_needmoreparams::Prototype(), err_alreadyregistred::Prototype(),
         rpl_endofmotd::Prototype()},
        std::chrono::seconds(5));

    // Ultimately, i want to check that 'res' was of a particular type,
    // which i intended to do by comparing its prototype against one of
    // the above prototypes, but this is a stand-in for that.
    // Removing this line makes the warning go away.
    std::cout << res->getPrototype().commandSymbol() << std::endl;

    return res;
}
```

It is worth noting that the `getPrototype` call angering the compiler here is on `protobase` rather than on an instantiation `numeric_impl`, which makes the warning even more confusing.

Interestingly, removing the `getPrototype` call above causes the warning not to be raised. Alternatively, creating instances of all the numeric types used (and calling `getPrototype` on those) also makes it go away:

```cpp
std::cout << err_nonicknamegiven(std::list<std::string>{}).getPrototype().commandSymbol() << std::endl;
std::cout << err_erroneusnickname(std::list<std::string>{}).getPrototype().commandSymbol() << std::endl;
std::cout << err_nicknameinuse(std::list<std::string>{}).getPrototype().commandSymbol() << std::endl;
std::cout << err_nickcollision(std::list<std::string>{}).getPrototype().commandSymbol() << std::endl;
std::cout << err_alreadyregistred(std::list<std::string>{}).getPrototype().commandSymbol() << std::endl;
std::cout << rpl_endofmotd(std::list<std::string>{}).getPrototype().commandSymbol() << std::endl;
std::cout << err_needmoreparams(std::list<std::string>{}).getPrototype().commandSymbol() << std::endl;
```

This workaround is obviously not very practical, but it leads me to believe the error is related to only using static methods of these types in this context; it seems that the template is instantiated and the compiler thus becomes aware of the `getPrototype` call, yet does not generate code for it (leading to the "never defined" bit of the error).

An example of successful usage of `getPrototype()` (this time, on `numeric_base`) is the following, which accompanies the `numeric_base` class in another translation unit:

```cpp
bool numeric_base::operator==(const numeric_base& other) const {
    return getPrototype() == other.getPrototype() && m_args == other.m_args;
}
```

Again, this is in a place where none of the specific numeric types are mentioned, so it has nothing to complain about.

The definition of `numeric_impl` is as follows:

```cpp
template <const char* NumericCode, const char* SymbolicName, int NumArgs>
class numeric_impl : public numeric_base {
public:
    template <typename Container>
    numeric_impl(Container const& args) : numeric_base(args) {}

    std::string serialize() const override {
        // omitted
    };

    prototype getPrototype() const override { return s_prototype; }

    static prototype Prototype() { return s_prototype; }

protected:
    static const prototype s_prototype;
};

template <const char* NumericCode, const char* SymbolicName, int NumArgs>
const prototype numeric_impl<NumericCode, SymbolicName, NumArgs>::s_prototype = {NumericCode, SymbolicName, NumArgs, 0,
                                                                                 false};
```

It would be simple enough to ignore the warning, but I feel like something more insidious is happening here. Not to mention that having a deeper understanding of what the compiler is thinking here would certainly be nice. Any insight would be very appreciated.

Comment: The definition isn't visible from whatever source code is being compiled when the error message is shown.

Comment: The translation unit from which the error is thrown has included the header with the definition. Logically, it would not see the declaration if it could not see the definition. Something more subtle is happening here.

Comment: It is possible to reduce your example? For example, does this problem happen if you start with a new project and only include one function?

Comment: I tried to create a MWE of this condition with no success... It's incredibly hard to pinpoint exactly what is happening.

Comment: I had a similar issue, MCVE https://godbolt.org/z/ex_Agt - it's fixed since gcc 9. Could you try upgrading your compiler?

Comment: fwiw, it is possible to compile the godbolt snippet with gcc 5.x as well.

Comment: Link to gcc bug: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=80916